# How do I stop a node submission programmatically?

Tags: 8

i'm using Drupal 8. I would like to stop the user to submit a node when he tap save, and show some message. How can I do it programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the form submit button using [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) and show a link `Save and Publish` on form. And include a jQuery snippet to show message, which will be triggered when user clicks on a link `Save and Publish`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent form submission and show message, you can add form validation to your form (using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter):

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_MYNODETYPE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = '_node_MYNODETYPE_form_validate';
}

function _node_MYNODETYPE_form_validate($form, $form_state) {  
  // add some logic to show or not show message here
  $form_state->setErrorByName('field_MYFIELD', 'Message to show by my field');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid saving the results, you must remove (or override) the save function from the form.
Try this:

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{    
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][0] = "_custom_submit";
        unset($form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][1]); //Avoid save results    
}
```